# "Use Voice with Wired Headset" Notification Stops Music

Tags: audio, voice-recognition, google-assistant

I have my Moto G plugged into an AUX port in my car which plays music from the car's speaker's via Google Play Music. Occasionally, the music will automatically pause and a notification will popup on my phone saying "Use Voice with Wired Headset."

If I try to hit play again, Google Play Music will show the music playing, but nothing is coming from the speakers. In order to get it working again, I found I need to kill the Google Play Music app, unplug from the AUX cable, then reconnect and open the app. The process repeats every time the "Wired Headset" notification pops up. The frequency of the notification is random when driving.

I'm guessing the phone is picking up the music from my car's speakers and thinking it's me trying to give voice commands. I turned off all relevant settings concerning voice commands (Settings > Accessibility; Google Assistant > Settings > Voice), but it still occurs and I'm afraid a I'm missing something.

Anyone familiar with the problem or have an idea for a countermeasure?

Thanks!

Comment: Do other music playing apps like Apple Music, Spotify or amazon music do the same thing?

Comment: @William A this point, just Google Play Music

Answer (score 1):

No. The Internet is full random speculation about this issue, ranging from dirty/damaged headhone jack, to hardware issues and defective headphones. All of these lame excuses are wrong. Google Assistant has been intentionally written (several updates ago) to use this method of nagging harrassment to force Android users to enable "Ok Google"/Assistant. Just like your Google Feed cannot be shut off now without completely disabling the Google app entirely, and disabling Play, Gmail, etc along with it. It is just another form of "user herding" so they can further Snoop and send you focused advertising. Not happy with only gathering search terms, they want everyone on board with Voice, befotre they change the user agreement and eavesdrop on end users constantly. This is already happening to wide cross section of users, without any real consent or knowledge. Some of it Google has pushed off on third party affiliates to insulate themselves from inevitable push back and outrage. People are figuring this out, by conversations overheard by phones are changing their advertisment and news feeds.

Comment: We prefer constructive suggestions on this site, not wall-of-text rants.